# Get average per unit and filter query per year

Tags: sql-server, filter, average

I need some help with a code, I want to get the average Price per City and per Year from the following table.

```
    Date    City    Price
 10/23/2018 Leon    1088
 2/27/2018  NewYork 1312
 4/19/2017  Texas   1303
 4/19/2017  London  1303
 4/19/2019  NewYork 1303
 2/12/2018  Leon    1251
 4/7/2017   Leon    1170
 3/20/2019  London  1650
 12/18/2017 Texas   1358
 2/18/2019  Leon    1088
 7/3/2017   NewYork 1391
 8/8/2019   Texas   830
 4/5/2018   London  1869.5
 1/29/2018  London  1169
 8/9/2019   Texas   1130
```

Avgerage price should be calculated per city per year.
Results should be grouped by year and shown per each City as follows:

```
City       Avg2017    Avg2018    Avg2019
Leon        1170      1169.5     1088
London      1303      1519.25    1650
New York    1391      1312       1303
Texas       1330.5     0         1390
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try it dynamic query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(YEAR(c.[Date])) 
        FROM YourTableName c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')



SET @query = 'SELECT City, ' + @cols + ' FROM 
(

SELECT City,YEAR([Date]) AS AvgYear,AVG(Price) AS Price
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY City,YEAR([Date])

)AS CTEs

 PIVOT (
          MAX(Price)
          FOR AvgYear in (' + @cols + ')
       ) p
             '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks. Can you explain how it works and tell if this would be automated for future years. Or what is need in order to keep on showing the last 3 years of data from 1st January to 31st December every year?

Answer (score 1):

Try using aggregation with pivoting logic:

```
SELECT
    City,
    AVG(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(4), Date, 120) = '2017' THEN Price END) AS Avg2017,
    AVG(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(4), Date, 120) = '2018' THEN Price END) AS Avg2018,
    AVG(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(4), Date, 120) = '2019' THEN Price END) AS Avg2019
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    CONVERT(varchar(4), Date, 120) IN ('2017', '2018', '2019')
GROUP BY
    City;
```

Comment: Is there a way I can 'automate' this query so that when 2020 starts I don't have to add it manually? Is it possible to just get as much AVG(CASE WHEN... = 2020) up to next 30 years or something?

Comment: Generally no, you would need a fairly different approach using dynamic SQL.  You could consider writing a stored procedure to handle this requirement.